# How to access a controller injected services within $on listener defined within the same controller in AngulaJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, broadcast, emit

In AngularJS; How to access services injected into a controller within an `$on` listener defined within the same controller?

I have a controller (`myCtrl`) and I've defined an `$on` listener within it.
But I'm not able to access `myService` within the listener. Here's my code:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'myService', function($scope,myService) {
    $scope.$on('someEventFired', function(event, datafronEventThrower) {
        myService.callServiceMethos(datafronEventThrower);
    });
}]);
```

Comment: What do you mean by *But I couldn't able to access 'myService' within the listener*? Is it throwing any error?

Comment: if `myService` is properly injected, I don't see why it could fail when you call it.

Comment: Im getting an console error as :

uncaught reference error:  'myService' is  not defined

Comment: then show us the code you used to define `myService`

Comment: `app.factory('myService', ['$http', function($http) {
   var callServiceMethos = function() {
     return $http.get.....
   }
   return {
     callServiceMethos : callServiceMethos 
   };
});`

Comment: You forgot to close the array with ]

Comment: @nicolascolman I missed it while typing :) , in actual code its there

Answer (score 0):

If you are using $broadcast like this :

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('someEventFired', { any: {} });
```

Then receive the event and the args like this :

```
$scope.$on('someEventFired', function(event, args) {
    var anyThing = args.any;
});
```

Comment: Yes, but my question is i couldn't use use services injected to controller within the listener

Comment: Nothing in the navigator's log ? no error ? , try to create a function in the controller and call it from the $on function !

Comment: Its probably a problem in declaring the service, try to call the service outside the $on function

Comment: I think so, but i couldn't figure out what is the problem there

Comment: Did you include your service in the main html page ?